# How to align the radio buttons horizontally in angular material?

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-material

I was expecting a in-built directive or a tag for this but probably not according to their documentation.

This is the [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqEaZL).

```
<div class="radioButtondemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp">
<form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<p>Selected Value: <span class="radioValue">{{ data.group1 }}</span> </p>

<md-radio-group ng-model="data.group1">

  <md-radio-button value="Apple" class="md-primary">Apple</md-radio-button>
  <md-radio-button value="Banana"> Banana </md-radio-button>
  <md-radio-button value="Mango">Mango</md-radio-button>

</md-radio-group>
```

Answer (score 137, accepted):

**You do not need to override any default CSS:**

```
<md-radio-group layout="row">
  <md-radio-button value=0 class="md-primary">On</md-radio-button>
  <md-radio-button value=1> Off </md-radio-button>
</md-radio-group>
```

[image]

Just put in `md-radio-group` tag a `layout="row"` attribute.

Answer (score 8):

Better not override any existing class.

Use the directive `ng-style` and give value for display parameter.

```
<md-radio-group ng-model="selvalue">
  <md-radio-button value="A" class="md-primary" ng-style="{'display':'inline'}"> Apple</md-radio-button>
  <md-radio-button value="R" class="md-primary" ng-style="{'display':'inline'}"> Orange </md-radio-button>
</md-radio-group>
```

Comment: Works perfectly for Angular 5 (Material 2 v5.0).

Comment: To make it look little more accurate add

```md-radio-group[layout="row"] md-radio-button {
 margin: 10px;
}```

Answer (score 0):

If you use layout row and your radio group is in a row layout parent the text vertical aligin will break. The soulution is putting it in a empty wrapper element.

[image]

```
<div layout="row">
     ...
     <div>
        <md-radio-group ng-model="data.group1" aria-labelledby="favoriteFruit" layout="row">
          <md-radio-button value="Apple" class="md-primary">Apple</md-radio-button>
          <md-radio-button value="Banana">Banana</md-radio-button>
          <md-radio-button value="Mango">Mango</md-radio-button>
        </md-radio-group>
     </div>
     ...
</div>
```