# Align labels in a md-radio-button group

Tags: css, angularjs

I would like to vertically align the buttons of my md-radio-button group with their labels.

This is my HTML:

```
<md-radio-group ng-model="merchant.type">

    <md-radio-button value="small">Eine Niederlassung</md-radio-button>
    <md-radio-button value="medium">2-5 Niederlassungen</md-radio-button>
    <md-radio-button value="large">6 oder mehr Niederlassungen</md-radio-button>

</md-radio-group>
```

The output is:

[image: Output]

Any idea how the labels can be properly vertically aligned with their buttons?

Comment: Here are some links they may help you [md-radio-button](http://codepen.io/pen/) and [Angular Material radio buttons](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/radioButton)

Comment: Check this out!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31114973/how-to-align-the-radio-buttons-horizontally-in-angular-material

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, the issue was that the radio buttons were in a div like so:

```
<div layout="column" class="md-inline-form" ng-cloak>
```

I moved them outside of this div, and it now works!